# Multidimensional Scaling to plot points from distance matrix

Tags: python, plot, machine-learning, distance, mds

I am trying to plot a distance matrix of 7000*7000 using MDS.When i tried to plot just 500 points i got the plot but when i tried for all 7000 points the program is running endlessly

Plot for 500 points

[image]

I just want to visualize the distance matrix,what should i do?
Is there any other way out?